# PHP how to use regular exp to inject a timestamp to the name of the file

Tags: php, regex

i have a debug file

this file can be defined by admin system

such as ../debug.log, or ../folder1/folder.log/file.txt or ..\folder1\yx.log

how can i use regular exp to inject the timestamp to the file name for above string?

Comment: Please, explain better your need.

Comment: @user192344 This is just a shot in the dark, but you could use a tool like logrotate to handle this for you. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/how-to-add-my-log-files-in-logrotate-99503/

Comment: SO i cant just ask a question, but this question need to be in real scenario? since i just ask how to use regular exp to inject timestamp, like i ask how to use foreach logic, why you delete my comment above

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you would like to insert a timestamp into the filename, probably near the end, but the filename is user-defined, and therefore you don't know what the pattern will be. Regular expressions aren't needed -- you can do this with string operations.

You can replace the final occurrence of `.` with `-timestamp.`, or just append the timestamp if there is no `.` or a `/` follows the last `.` (for a case like `/logs/file.log/somelog`):

```
// If $filename contains no . or / comes after ., just append the date
if (strrpos($filename, ".") === FALSE || strrpos($filename, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) > strrpos($filename, ".")) {
   $filename .= "-" . date("Ymd");
}
// It contains a . so insert a timestamp
else {
  // Find the last "." and replace it with "-timestamp.", 
  // then append the file extension (everything following ".")
  $filename = substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, ".")) . "-" . date('Ymd') . substr($filename, strrpos($filename, "."));
}

// Example:
$filename = "/logs/mylog.txt";
// Output:
// /logs/mylog-20111031.txt

$filename = "/logs/mylog";
// Output:
// /logs/mylog-20111031

$filename "/logs/log.file/mylog";
// Output:
// /logs/log.file/mylog-20111031
```

Comment: that has a problem, if user define something like this /folder1/folder.log/file

Comment: @user192344 Indeed it did. And it is trivially solved by the addition of another condition to the `if()`, testing if `/` comes after `.`

Comment: how about --   folder1/folder.log/file.log, btw, thx for ur solution too

Comment: @user192344 Yes, if you examine the logic that case will work too. The final `.` comes after the final `/` even though there's another `.` inside.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not regex, but you could try this.

```
<?php

$filename = '../folder1/yx.log';
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$path = split($ds, $filename);
$path[] = $date.'_'.array_pop($path);
$filename = implode($ds, $path);

print_r($filename);

?>
```

Comment: this similar to wat i did currently